# is it possible to map string column to boolean field in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have a table in which i have a column with datatype char(3) and it can be either  YES or NULL. In the Java class, I want to map this column with a boolean field. I know that one should be defining column datatype as BIT but it cannot be done now.

is it possible to map string column to boolean field in hibernate

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL, you can use BOOLEAN as column type and you will be able to map to a getter/setter of type Boolean or boolean if you set your column to NOT NULL.

Using a STRING column the easiest way would be to do a class like that :

```
class MyObject
{
    private String _value;

    public void setValue(String value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public String getValue()
    {
        return _value;
    }

    public boolean getConvertedValue()
    {
        return getValue() != null;
    }

    public void setConvertedValue(boolean value)
    {
        setValue(value ? "YES" : null);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!